# Ordering list<T>

Tags: linq, generics

I have a list of custom objects List called jobList.  The list has many fields, but I want to sort by two fields, FolderID and JobName.  The list looks like this:

```
job.FolderID = 3
job.JobName = "oper01_quick"

job.FolderID = 3
Job.JobName = "oper02_quick"

job.FolderID = 1
job.JobName = "min01_selfie"

job.FolderID = 2
job.JobName = "max01_experion"

job.FolderID = 2
job.JobName = "max02_experion"
```

I want to sort this list so that it appears like this:

```
job.FolderID = 1
job.JobName = "min01_selfie"

job.FolderID = 2
job.JobName = "max01_experion"

job.FolderID = 2
job.JobName = "max02_experion"

job.FolderID = 3
job.JobName = "oper01_quick"

job.FolderID = 3
Job.JobName = "oper02_quick"
```

And I thought that if I did this LINQ OrderBy, ThenBy:

```
jobList.OrderBy(j => j.FolderID).ThenBy(j => j.JobName);
```

that it would accomplish this.  But it doesn't.  It make the order look like this:

```
job.FolderID = 1
job.JobName = "min01_selfie"

job.FolderID = 2
job.JobName = "max01_experion"

job.FolderID = 3
job.JobName = "oper01_quick"

job.FolderID = 2
job.JobName = "max02_experion"

job.FolderID = 3
Job.JobName = "oper02_quick"
```

Can anyone help me with ordering the list properly ?

Thanks,

Chewdoggie

Comment: Can we assume `FolderID` is an `int` and `JobName` is a `string`?

Comment: Can you share the actual code instead of just writing out a list of some kind of stuff in a code block?

Comment: Did you assign result of `OrderBy().ThenBy` calls to something? These methods don't sort in place. They create new collection with items sorted.

Comment: I created a `Job` class that mirrors yours, and then used the same calls to `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` and it sorted correctly.  Marcin is correct in pointing out that the list does not get sorted in-place - you'll need to assign the result of the methods to something.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in how you're doing the sorting, but you need to assign it to a variable in order to get the resulting sorted collection:

See the .NET Fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/wISQVv

This is essentially what it does:

```
var sortedJobs = jobs.OrderBy(j => j.FolderID).ThenBy(j => j.JobName);

foreach(var job in sortedJobs){
    Console.WriteLine(job.FolderID + " " + job.JobName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see only one possible explenation: you're not assigning `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` result back to your source variable.

These methods (and the entire LINQ) does not change source collection. Instead of that, they create new collection with elements sorted. That's why you have to assign it back:

```
jobList = jobList.OrderBy(j => j.FolderID).ThenBy(j => j.JobName).ToList();
```

To sort list in place you have to use `Sort` method, with custom comparer:

```
public class JobComparer : IComparer<Job>
{
    public int Compare(Job x, Job y)
    {
        var folderDifference = x.FolderId.CompareTo(y.FolderId);
        return folderDifference == 0 ? x.JobName.CompareTo(y.JobName) : folderDifference;
    }
}
```

```
jobList.Sort(new JobComparer());
```

Comment: if he isn't assign it then he should get the same result with original list.But results are different, so that's not the problem

Comment: @Selman22 I can't see different explanation. Even if `FolderId` is a string, it would sort `"2"` and `"3"` items correctly...

Comment: Yes,but after first sort, it is sorting by JobName then, `"3,oper01_quick"` comes before `"2,max02_experion"`

Comment: @Selman22 But `ThenBy` is only applied to sub-group of items which are considers equal from previous sort definition, so `JobName` would be checked for the same `FolderId` values only.

Comment: hmm, I didn't know that. it seems you right, I tried that query and it gave the correct result.But still don't understand how is the OP get different result.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
jobs.OrderBy(j => j.JobName).OrderBy(j => j.FolderId)
```

Seems to be working fine.

Comment: Didn't you meant to use `ThenBy` on the second operator? `OrderBy` ignores any previous ordering.

Comment: No, it's exactly that syntax I used in the LINQPAD, I would guess the second orderby is applied on the result of the first one.

Comment: It is. But [`ThenBy` performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in ascending order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx "Enumerable.ThenBy Method") while [`OrderBy` sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx "Enumerable.OrderBy Method"). (...)

Comment: (...) The difference is in the subsequent and the argument. `OrderBy` operates on [enumerables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9eekhta0.aspx "IEnumerable<T> Interface") and [queriables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb351562.aspx "IQueryable<T> Interface") while `ThenBy` operates on [ordered enumerables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534852.aspx "IOrderedEnumerable<TElement> Interface") and [ordered queriables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340178.aspx "IOrderedQueryable<T> Interface").

Answer (score 0):

If your `Job` class looks like  this:

```
public class Job
{
    public int FolderId { get; set; }

    public string JobName { get; set; }
}
```

Then implement `IComparer<T>`:

```
public class JobComparer : IComparer<Job>
{
    public int Compare(Job x, Job y)
    {
        if (x.FolderId != y.FolderId) return x.FolderId.CompareTo(y.FolderId);

        return x.JobName.CompareTo(y.JobName);
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
var orderedList = items.OrderBy(x => x, new JobComparer()).ToList();
```

This should give your expected result.Here is the output in `LINQPad`:

[image]